# How to convert geo coordinates to meters with a specific starting point?

Tags: geolocation, gis, geocoding

I need to convert geo coordinates to meters. I already learned about proj4 and etc.
But I need to be able to specify the "zero" coordinate from which the countdown of meters will begin. And the error should be less than 500 meters.
Is it possible?

Comment: The 'net abounds with sites which explain how to calculate (to whatever degree of accuracy you wish) the distance in metres between two points on the earth's surface.  Can you explain what you mean by the 'zero' coordinate ?

Comment: I have a list  latitude/longitude coordinates. I need to convert these coordinates into the Cartesian coordinate system with a minimum step of 1 meter. Point (0, 0) is known in the format of latitude, longitude.

Comment: Investigate the *Universal Transverse Mercator* coordinate system.

Answer (score 1):

Two approaches:

1) UTM: This system has predefined origin and all the meters grids are calculated from there. However the calculation are almost accurate
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system

2) 
meters_XY=LatLonToMeters(x,y)
meters_xOrigin_yOrigin=LatLonToMeters(xOrigin,yOrigin)
Take difference of meters_XY and meters_xOrigin_yOrigin. This way you will have meters from your origin.

Code for LatLonToMeters is available at:
https://github.com/Prafulljohri/gmap-tile-generator/blob/master/gmaps-tile-creator/src/gov/ca/maps/tile/geom/GlobalMercator.java